# Do chocolate bars cause pimples?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, biology, disease

My mother always told me "eating that chocolate bar will give you pimples." Is there any truth to the claim?

I did find an article on about.com that verifies that this is a common myth, and suggests that chocolate bars do not cause acne: [Does Eating Chocolate Cause Acne?](http://acne.about.com/od/acnefaqs/f/chocolate.htm)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a study demonstrating that cocoa, which differs chocolate from other sweets is not responsible.

Study in question is Fulton JE Jr, Plewig G, Kligman AM. *"Effect of chocolate on acne vulgaris."* The Journal of the American Medical Association. 1969 Dec 15;210(11):2071-4. Cited in PubMed; PMID 4243053.

> The 1969 study was aimed at
>   determining whether chocolate and acne
>   are related. Two groups were given
>   chocolate bars. One group was given
>   chocolate bars with zero cocoa
>   content, and the other group was given
>   chocolate bars with a huge cocoa
>   content. The two groups fared equally
>   well as far as their acne was
>   concerned. However, the chocolate bars
>   both had sugar, milk, etc. The study
>   was only testing cocoa in particular.

However, what's nowadays called "chocolate bar" has actually very little chocolate at all. It's mainly sugar in various forms. For example [Mars bar is 60% sugar (35g of 58g)](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calories/mars-mars-bar-11372641).

[Sugars are known to induce acne](http://www.dermaharmony.com/adultacne/dietinsulinandyourskin.aspx):

> high-glycemic diets, with their higher
>   carbohydrate and sugar contributions,
>   generally do give rise to increased
>   plasma levels of insulin.
>   High-glycemic diets also promote
>   increased blood levels of another
>   substance: free insulin-like growth
>   factor (IGF-1).
>
> IGF-1 is thought to promote acne in a
>   similar way to insulin, by promoting
>   follicular obstruction through
>   inducing androgen-mediated sebum
>   production, but also hyperkeratosis, a
>   thickening of the outer layers of
>   skin, and epidermal hyperplasia, a
>   proliferation of skin cells. A study
>   of post-adolescent women, ages 20–25
>   years, found increased levels of IGF-1
>   in those suffering from acne.

So given that it's fair to say that eating excess of candy bars (aka "chocolate" bars) could induce acne.