# Is there a correlation between diet and acne?

Tags: nutrition, acne

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do oily foods have any effect on acne?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/do-oily-foods-have-any-effect-on-acne)

Is there a correlation between diet and acne? I've always assumed there was, but I'm not sure of the source of my assumption. I humorously label greasy foods as "pimple fertilizer". But what are the facts? What sort of studies/experiments have been done on this topic?

I found [a related, but unanswered question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/do-oily-foods-have-any-effect-on-acne) which the community here showed some interest in. But I wanted to broaden the question to allow for more answers.

Comment: related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4902/do-chocolate-bars-cause-pimples - this pretty much answers you question partially - there is correlation between diet and acne.

Comment: That does _partially_ answer my question. Thanks :)